# Can a tea light really heat a greenhouse?

Tags: thermodynamics, estimation, diffusion, thermal-conduction

It is a common suggestion amongst greenhouse enthusiasts that a long-burning [tea light](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tealight) inside an upturned terracotta pot can be enough to keep frost away from plants. Is this possible?

Instinctively, it feels wrong: in winter, a greenhouse does not retain heat well so I don't feel a candle can output enough heat to be noticeable, see e.g. [this](https://www.gardenmyths.com/myth-clay-pot-heaters/).

From what I could find out, a regular tea light has about $550$kJ of energy. The long-burning ones I would guess, are twice as much so let's say $1100$kJ. Regarding power, they can produce $30$ watts of heat according to [this](https://www.gardenmyths.com/myth-clay-pot-heaters/) source.
Let's say the greenhouse is smallish, about $2.5$m$\times 2$m.
I'm not sure where to go from here to calculate the candle's effect.

[image]

Comment: Dear Ian, the answer seems to depend on many technical details, so it is more an "engineering" question. However, a "back of the envelope" estimate or a simple upper limit on the effect of the candle is probably possible, which makes this question suitable for this website if addressed in this sense (this is just my opinion, other users may find the question more relevant to another SE website).

Comment: this  might interest you https://hartley-botanic.com/magazine/greenhouse-heating/

Comment: What is the purpose of the terracotta pots?

Comment: @quillo if you say that the question depends upon _technical details_ then pretty well all of experimental physics becomes *engineering*. All your base are belong to us.

Comment: @jkej: Presumably they act as heat diffusers. A candle flame is a small hot spot that emits much of its heat as visible light (which can escape straight through the transparent walls of a greenhouse) and in a small plume of very hot gas (which will rise up quickly and mostly heat the ceiling). The pots will absorb this heat and re-radiate it as thermal infrared (which the walls aren't transparent to) and also help mix the hot gases with the surrounding cold air. They'll probably also help a bit with fire safety, making it less likely for something flammable to touch the flames and catch fire.

Comment: @DDuck I think the line between what is engineering and what is physics can be fuzzy, but questions like this are what made physics interesting to me - applying physics to everyday life to gain a simple understanding of normally complicated phenomena.

Comment: @Jono94 just trying to say that this question is in the grey area between physics and engineering. The engineering question would be: _what are my options on how I can most effectively and at lowest cost heat my greenhouse?_

Answer (score 14, accepted):

"a greenhouse in the winter does not retain heat well"

This is the crucial point: the rate of heat loss will be roughly proportional to the temperature difference between the inside of the greenhouse and the outside. You typically lose through the glass about 6 joule per second per m$^2$ of glass per °C of temperature difference. We write:

$U_{glass} = 6\ \text {W m}^{-2}\ \text {°C}^{-1}$

If the temperature difference is $\Delta T$ and the glass area is $A$, the rate of heat loss, $Q/t$ will be

$$Q/t = U_{glass}\ A\ \Delta T$$

Using the floor-area you have chosen for your greenhouse and assuming a mean height of 2.5 m, I crudely estimate that $A=30\ \text m^2$

A tea-light, it seems, gives out about 32 W (32 J/s). So by putting $Q/t=32\ \text{J/s}$ we can work out the temperature difference that the tea light could maintain between the inside and outside...

$$\Delta T=\frac {Q/t}{U_{glass}A}=\frac{32\ \text W}{6\ \text {W m}^{-2}\ \text {°C}^{-1}\ 30\ \text m^2}=0.2\ \text{°C}$$

This isn't very impressive is it? And, of course, the tea-light may have to burn for several minutes before this equilibrium temperature difference is established. To be fair , the temperature inside the greenhouse won't be uniform, and it's quite possible that plants *near* the potted tea-light might be preserved from frost even when the outside temperature is a few degrees below zero.

Comment: I think you have meant "steady state temperature difference" not "equilibrium temperature difference"

Comment: @hyportnex Thanks. Your phrase is more precise.

Comment: That said, it seems like a dozen tea lights or so *would* be able to protect the greenhouse from a light frost, which might make it a reasonable course of action to try if you don't have another option.

Comment: I like the calculation, but greenhouses are *diligently* designed to insulate well and most sold today are made out of PVC or Polycarbonate,  https://www.greenhousecatalog.com/greenhouse-insulation which have U values of 0.5-0.6. So that's 10x. And the picture shows four candles so 4x?

Comment: An anti-frost strategy I find appealing – without having tried it – is to leave tubs of water in the greenhouse. They will retain some thermal energy acquired through solar gain in the daytime, and if at night they cool enough to start to freeze they will release latent heat that will tend to stop the air in the greenhouse from cooling much below 0 °C.

Comment: @Pentane I believe you on the topic of modern greenhouses; I based my answer on our ten-year-old glass greenhouse. Using your U value for the plastic would raise the steady state temperature difference attainable to about 2 °C, which might protect plants from light frosts.  And with 4 tea lights, we're approaching the dizzying heights of 8 °C !

Comment: Ours is toughened glass which I am guess will fair slightly better than regular horticultural glace but not much. So, it seems perhaps there is some merit in it if the outside temp is likely to be just below freezing it, then it may help. But colder than that and it's going to need a lot of tea lights.

Comment: It seems like the flowerpots would increase the amount of airflow around the tea lights, but I have no idea how to estimate the effect on their output power.

Comment: Thinking about it, how well draft proofed the greenhouse is will probably matter too.

Comment: @PhilipWood I did try containers of water. But it was hard to say it made any difference.. Certainly by morning the inside temp and the outside temp were about the same.

Comment: @Ian Cox  Interesting. I wonder if the outside temperature was above or below 0 °C. I suspect that the water containers are only really useful under 0 °C when the latent heat is released.

Comment: @TannerSwett But if a long-burning tealight would normally burn for 6-8 hours (and a regular one half that), making them burn faster and hotter might not be a great idea, if you need them to last overnight!

Answer (score 3):

This is a heat transfer rate problem.

The rate of heat generated by the combustion minus the rate of heat transferred through the walls to the outside environment.  The bigger this number, the warmer it will be inside.

Here is a good example for you to look at:

https://www.greenhousemag.com/article/basic-greenhouse--engineering-calculations/